# Local $\partial \bar{\partial}$-lemma..

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

I am trying to prove the local $\partial \bar{\partial}$ lemma.
This says that for a polydisc in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, a form in $A^{p,q}(U)$ being $d$-closed implies that it is $\partial \bar{\partial}$-exact. 
I've tried to use the $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ Poincare lemma's to no avail.. I'd like a hint as to where I should get started, I'd greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:

Due to my lack of conceptual tools and methods of approach.. I guess I would like to try going down this avenue:

Given that my form (say, $\alpha$) is $d$-closed, it is $\partial$-closed. By Poincare's lemma, I can find a form $\gamma$ in $A^{p-1,q}(U)$ such that $\partial \gamma = \alpha$. As a stab in the dark, I would like to attempt to decompose $\gamma$ as $P + \bar{\partial}Q$ for a $\partial$-closed form $P$. 
If I can accomplish this, then $\partial \gamma = \partial (P + \bar{\partial}Q)  = \partial \bar{\partial}Q$ and I'll be done.

Do you think that this is a long shot? I'm just trying to get my hands dirty and actually expanding and applying $\partial$ to the terms to see if I can fuddle around enough to arise at such a decomposition..

This arises as an exercise in Huybrecht's book "Complex geometry". It is exercise 1.3.4/1.3.3

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to assume that $p$ and $q$ are both positive; otherwise there are no nontrivial $(p-1,q-1)$-forms. You'll need to use both the ordinary Poincaré lemma and the $\partial$- and $\overline\partial$-Poincaré lemmas.

First, if $\alpha$ is a $d$-closed $(p,q)$ form on $U$, then the ordinary Poincaré lemma implies that $\alpha=d\eta$ for some complex $p+q-1$-form $\eta$. Since the only parts of $\eta$ that can contribute to the $(p,q)$-part of $d\eta$ are the $(p,q-1)$ and $(p-1,q)$ parts, we may as well assume that $\eta$ decomposes as $\eta =\eta^{(p,q-1)}+\eta^{(p-1,q)}$. Using the fact that $d=\partial+\overline\partial$, we can decompose the equation $d\eta=\alpha$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\partial\eta ^{(p,q-1)}&= 0 &&\text{($(p+1,q-1)$-part)}\\
\overline\partial\eta^{(p,q-1)} + \partial\eta^{(p-1,q)} &= \alpha&&\text{($(p,q)$-part})\\
\overline\partial\eta ^{(p-1,q)}&= 0 &&\text{($(p-1,q+1)$-part)}.
\end{align*}
Now apply the $\partial$- and $\overline\partial$-Poincaré lemmas to conclude that there exist $(p-1,q-1)$-forms $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\partial \beta=\eta^{(p,q-1)}$ and $\overline\partial \gamma=\eta^{(p-1,q)}$. You can probably take it from there.

Comment: Perfect! I forgot about the ordinary Poincare lemma.. it turned out to be quite easy, when you put it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jack's answer is not correct. We may not assume $\eta=\eta^{(p,q-1)}+\eta^{(p-1,q)}$ since we may need the terms of other types to cancel $\partial \eta^{(p,q-1)}$ and $\bar{\partial} \eta^{(p-1,q)}$.

Here is a correct approach. Let $n=p+q-1$ and decompose $\eta$ with $d\eta=\alpha$ into parts $\eta^{(k,n-k)}$ of type $(k,n-k)$. By looking at the components of $d\eta$ of extremal type $(n+1,0)$ and $(0,n+1)$ we conclude $\partial \eta^{(n,0)}=\bar{\partial}\eta^{(0,n)}=0$. By the Poincaré lemmas, $\eta^{(n,0)}=\partial \gamma_n$ and $\eta^{(0,n)}=\bar{\partial} \rho_n$. And so, $\bar{\partial} \eta^{(n,0)}=-\partial\bar{\partial}\gamma_n$ and $\partial \eta^{(0,n)} = \partial\bar{\partial} \rho_n$ are $\partial\bar\partial$-exact.

In the case $p$ and/or $q>1$, from the equation $d\eta = \alpha$ in types $(n,1)$ and $(1,n)$ we find that,
$$\partial \eta^{(n-1,1)} = -\bar\partial\eta^{(n,0)} = \partial\bar\partial\gamma_n \quad\text{   and  }\quad \bar\partial \eta^{(1,n-1)}=-\partial \eta^{(0,n)} = -\partial\bar\partial \rho_n.$$
From the Poincaré lemma, $\eta^{(n-1,1)}-\bar\partial\gamma_n=\partial\gamma_{n-1}$ and $\eta^{(1,n-1)}-\partial\rho_n=\bar\partial \rho_{n-1}$. Thus, $\bar\partial \eta^{(n-1,1)} = -\partial\bar\partial\gamma_{n-1}$ and $\partial\eta^{(1,n-1)}=\partial\bar{\partial}\rho_{n-1}$ are $\partial\bar\partial$-exact.

This extends inductively to give that $\bar\partial \eta^{(p,q-1)} = -\partial\bar\partial\gamma_{p}$ and $\partial\eta^{(p-1,q)}=\partial\bar{\partial}\rho_{q}$ are $\partial\bar\partial$-exact. But then from $d\eta=\alpha$ in type $(p,q)$,
$$\alpha = \partial\eta^{(p-1,q)} + \bar\partial \eta^{(p,q-1)} = \partial\bar{\partial}(\rho_q-\gamma_p), $$
as desired.