# the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma dilemma

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In the question here [Simplifying the Kahler form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531776/simplifying-the-kahler-form/1531789?noredirect=1#comment3205641_1531789), user290605 asked a question about how is that when we take the differential of Kahler form:$$\mathcal{K}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi}g_{i\bar{j}}dz^i\wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{j}},$$ we get$$\partial_ig_{j\bar{k}}=\partial_jg_{i\bar{k}} \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} \partial_{\bar{i}}g_{j\bar{k}}=\partial_{\bar{k}}g_{j\bar{i}}.\hspace{1cm} (2)$$ Then, was my question, that  how starting from (2)
(for example here [p.45](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=sfUICAAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=we%20now%20define%20a%20hermitian%20manifold%20as%20a%20complex%20manifold%20where%20there%20is%20preferred%20class%20of%20coordinate&source=bl&ots=lS_eMIl13j&sig=arjL5QBrRexp5382VbyltH6_C5U&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdmIHI0dfJAhVBUhoKHQJ_AbwQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=we%20now%20define%20a%20hermitian%20manifold%20as%20a%20complex%20manifold%20where%20there%20is%20preferred%20class%20of%20coordinate&f=false))] do we get $$g_{i\bar{k}}=∂_i∂_\bar{k}K(z,\bar{z})$$ where $K(z,\bar{z})$ is the Kahler potential?

As you can see, John, answered me there by saying that

> That follows from the fact that $\mathcal{K}$ is closed and of type
> $(1,1)$. This is called the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma and the
> proof can be found in (e.g.) p.14 of [this note](http://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf). Note that
> $\bar{\partial}$-Poincare lemma is needed.

However, as a physicist I am not familiar with this lemma and would really appreciate if anyone can elaborate on this more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $\partial\overline{\partial}$-lemma says that a closed (1,1)-form $\omega$ *locally* arises as $\partial\overline{\partial}f$ for some smooth function $f$. This is in the same spirit as the regular Poincare lemma (which says closed differential forms are locally exact) but instead of exactness meaning "equal to d(something)", as in the Poincare lemma, it here means $\partial\overline{\partial}$(something). It is worth remembering that the Poincare lemma is true on all smooth manifolds, the $\overline{\partial}$-lemma (in which 'exactness' means $\overline{\partial}$(something)) is true on all complex manifolds, but we only have a general proof of the $\partial\overline{\partial}$-lemma on Kahler manifolds, which is one of the reasons they are distinctly important.

Comment: thanks for your answer John, so let me rephrase this in order to see if I understand your point. You're saying that the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma says that every time we have a closed form on a complex manifold, we can write it as $\partial\bar{\partial}$(of some function, in our case, the function is $K(z,\bar{z}))$. Is this correct? If this is correct, my question now is why did the author and if you can see on p.45 of the link above says that it follows from the equations similar to equations (2) in my question above? (I will continue in another comment)

Comment: Because I am now seeing that there's absolutely no need to find equations (2) in order to reach this form: $$g_{i\bar{k}}=∂_i∂_\bar{k}K(z,\bar{z})$$, right? Another thing, I want to ask about notation, is $\partial\bar{\partial}K(z,\bar{z})$ the same thing as $∂_i∂_\bar{k}K(z,\bar{z})$? If so we're on the right track, but why didn't we bring anything up concerning $g_{i\bar{k}}$ and its appearance in the interplay?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: you have to be a bit careful - I'm not saying that my conclusion holds whenever we are given a closed form on a complex manifold. I'm saying it holds when we are given a closed (1,1)-form on a Kahler manifold (the result holds for forms of more general type, but we needn't worry about those for now). As for your claim that we don't need equations of type (2), if that's the case then how do you propose to find $K$ otherwise?

Comment: Are you generally comfortable working with differential forms on smooth manifolds? How about on complex manifolds?

Comment: Yes, I am comfortable working with them on smooth manifolds, this is my first encounter with complex manifolds though. I should also tell you that I have dealt with 1, 2, 3, .. - forms but not with mixed forms as you and John Ma in the other post mentioned, e.g. (1,1)-forms. So, also this is my first time I deal with this type of forms.

Comment: As for your first question, that's what have confused me to start with, i.e. where did the $K(z, \bar{z})$ come from and how did we benefit from equations (2) ? Where did $g_{i\bar{k}}=\partial_i\partial_{\bar{k}}K(z,\bar{z})$ pop out as a whole entity all of a sudden?

Comment: Ok so I think there are a few things to say. First: since you haven't worked with forms on complex manifolds, you should probably read up about this theory (*Complex Geometry* by Huybrechts is a good text) to clarify the definitions of holomorphic, antiholomorphic and general mixed-type forms on complex manifolds. In particular, the decomposition into type descends to the level of cohomology whenever the manifold is compact Kahler as a consequence of the Hodge theorem.

Comment: Second: since you are a physicist, it is probably worthwhile to point out that a Kahler form (e.g. the form $\mathscr{K}$ in your question) is in particular a symplectic form which happens to be compatible with the almost complex structure of the complex manifold. Third: the $K$ functions are the local Kahler potentials whose existence is *the result of* the $\partial\overline{\partial}$-lemma.

Comment: right, and as for the final form in question, $g_{i\bar{k}}=\partial_i\partial_{\bar{k}}K(z,\bar{z})$? Where did this come from? If you could help me with this, as this is my question, I could then decided what to read on the subject later on because to me this is very confusing. I can't read a whole text book to find out about one lemma that's why I posted this here and would be glad if you could help me with my original question as we're seeming to run around the question without directing it.

Comment: The equations (2) amount to showing that $\mathscr{K} = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi}g_{ij}dz^i\wedge d\overline{z}^j$ is a *closed* form. Since it is closed, the $\partial\overline{\partial}$-lemma says that such $K$ functions (Kahler potentials) exist. If you want to see some part of the construction of such $K$ functions (they are not unique) you should read the proof of the $\partial\overline{\partial}$-lemma on p.14 of the note in your own question, as well as some proof of the $\overline{\partial}$-Poincare-lemma.

Comment: Ok, so John, let me explain where I am getting lost. The lemma says that if it closed (1,1) form, we can write it as $\partial\bar{\partial}$(of some function, in our case it is K). Right? Ok, so my confusion arises from the fact that I cannot comprehend how mathematically speaking $\mathcal{K}=\partial\bar{\partial}K$ is equivalent to $g_{i\bar{k}}=\partial_i\partial_{\bar{k}}K$? In other words, where did the $g_{i\bar{k}}$ and the partials with the lower indices $i$ and $\bar{k}$ come form? I hope I made myself clear in this comment. Thanks John.

Comment: It looks like your confusion is largely concerned with working in local coordinates. What you said at the beginning of your last comment is not correct: we can only apply the $\partial\overline{\partial}$-lemma to a closed form *locally* - it does not yield such a global result. The $g_{ij}$ functions are used to give a *local* expression of the form $\mathcal{K}$ in some local coordinate patch where the lemma can be applied. The partials with the lower indices are also local coordinate representatives for the operators $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$. This notation is standard.

Comment: Uhhh ok ok, I got it now. So, there's nothing mathematically fancy that I should carry from that lemma to the final form $g_{i\bar{k}}=\partial_i\partial_{\bar{k}}K$. It is just the mere application of a theorem, isn't it? And the fact that $K$ is a function of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ is because the function should be smooth and so it can be as a function of nothing except $z$ and $\bar{z}$, right? Thanks a lot for bearing with my confusion.

Comment: Right - that expression comes straight from the lemma. There's nothing in between. You're welcome

Comment: Is it not true that the [local $\partial \bar \partial$-lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434389/local-partial-bar-partial-lemma) works on arbitrary complex manifolds (since it works on polydiscs), but the *global* $\partial \bar \partial$-lemma, which gives a globally defined $f$ with $\partial \bar \partial f = \omega$, requires a Kähler manifold?