# All Kahler structures on a compact Riemann surface

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface, is it possible to have a description for the space of all Khaler forms on $X$? More concretely, given two Kahler forms $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ is it known what is the relationship bethween them?

I know for sure that any compact Riemann surface is a hermitian manifold, which in turns is always Kalher (in dimension $1$); but I am asking about the relationship about two different Kahler structures.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What sort of relation are you asking?

Comment: Are you looking for something of the type "There is a unique positive real $c$ such that $\Omega$ is cohomologous to $c\Omega'$, and therefore a smooth, complex-valued function, unique up to an added constant, such that $\Omega = c\Omega' + i\partial\bar{\partial}\phi$"?

Comment: yes exactly this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$So this has an answer: The $(1,1)$-dimensional cohomology of a compact Riemann surface $X$ is one-dimensional, so any two Kähler classes are positively proportional: If $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ are smooth Kähler forms on $X$, there exists a unique positive real number $c$ such that $\Omega$ and $c\Omega'$ are cohomologous. The [$\dd\bar{\dd}$-lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577068/the-partial-bar-partial-lemma-dilemma) then guarantees there exists a smooth, real-valued function $\phi$ satisfying $\Omega = c\Omega'+ i\dd\bar{\dd}\phi$.